# How can I get the camera image using, for example, Sprite.create? Any idea?

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d

I try to get a camera picture in a sprite and I have this syntax of my another way to get the image.

```
Texture2D screenshot = new Texture2D(NatCam.Preview.width, NatCam.Preview.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
```

How can I get the camera image using, for example, `Sprite.create`?
Any idea how?

Comment: natcam is a plugin, but I can not use the plugin either

Comment: What do you mean by you can not use the plugin?

Comment: Yes, but I think I have already solved the problem using this implementation: WebCamTexture myWebcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        myWebcamTexture.Play();
        preview .texture = myWebcamTexture;                                                              the preview is a rawimage

Answer (score 0):

You can use a render texture. It lets you render a 2D image from a camera input in real time.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html